# How to get post, page or taxonomy ID under add_action('customize_register', ...) - WP Customize

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I try to get current queried_object ID under customize_register action...

```
// call action customize register
add_action('customize_register','register_customize_options');


//customize register callback function 
function register_customize_options( $wp_customize ){

//if is page customize preview
if( is_page() ):  //not work

   $ObjID = get_the_ID(); //not work

//if is any taxonomy customize preview
elseif ( is_tax() ) : //not work

   $ObjID =  get_queried_object()->term_id; //not work

endif;

// obj $wp_customize;
// var_dump( $wp_customize ); //not found any ID 

//rest of code... 

}
```

Also I try get page ID by `url_to_postid( $_GET['url'] )`, that is work just if user open customize on the page.

Any suggestion how to get dynamically Object ID under customize_register action?

Answer (score 0):

How to get post, page or taxonomy ID?
you can add below function in function.php

```
//customize register callback function 
function register_customize_options( $wp_customize ){

    if(is_page() || is_single() )
    {
         $ObjID = get_the_ID();

    }

    $term = get_queried_object();
    if ($term )
    {
        if ( is_category() || is_tag() ||  is_tax()) {
            $ObjID =  $term->term_id;
        }
    }

    return $ObjID;

    // obj $wp_customize;
    // var_dump( $wp_customize ); //not found any ID 

    //rest of code... 

}
add_action('customize_register','register_customize_options');
```

Comment: Thanks for update, but that don't work for me.

Are you try that on your WP installation ?